# Search users profile based on image on social media and display their information on a different page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, axios

I want to search users profile based on image on social media and display their information on a different page.But it doesn't display the user's complete profile like it's on social media.

For every social media a different page and on that page user's specific data but in a formatted way like it's on their profile on let's say Twitter. When I upload image ,based on that uploaded image it should display info. related to the image from every social media platform. So far this what I have done :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class SearchProfile extends Component {

  state = {
    image: null,
    profileUrls: []
  };

  onImageChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      image: event.target.files[0]
    });
  };

  searchProfiles = () => {
    const base64Image = this.state.image.base64;
    const url = `https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?q=image&imageUrl=data:image/jpeg;base64,${base64Image}`;

    axios.get(url).then(
      (response) => {
        if (response.status === 200) {
          const json = response.data;
          this.setState({
            profileUrls: json.items.map((item) => item.link)
          });
        }
      },
      (error) => {
        console.error(error);
      }
    );
  };

  render() {
    const { image, profileUrls } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <input type="file" accept="image/*" onChange={this.onImageChange} />
        <button onClick={this.searchProfiles}>Search Profiles</button>
        <ul>
          {profileUrls.map((url) => (
            <li key={url}>
              <a href={url}>{url}</a>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


export default SearchProfile;
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.